# variable errors in Java

Tags: java, variables

When I do my program, I get an error.
That's the last part of my programing.

```
public static double calculateTuition(int hour, char major, char state) {
   int rate;
   int labfee;
   double statusfee;
   if (hour >= 12) {
         int rate = 800;
   } else {
      int rate = hour * 70;
   }
   if (major == 'C'||major == 'c') {
      int labfee = 25;
   } else if (major == 'O'||major == 'o') {
      int labfee = 35;
   } else if (major == 'X'||major == 'x') {
      int labfee = 0;
   }
   if (state == 'Y'||state == 'y') {
      double statusfee = 5;
   } else if (state == 'N'||state == 'n') {
      double statusfee = 5+ rate*.2;      
   }
   double tuition = rate+labfee+statusfee;
   return tuition;
}
```

The error is error:

> variable rate is already defined in method
>   calculateTuition(int,char,char)

and labfee, statusfee have same errors.
total: there are 7 errors.

Comment: you define each variable multiple times, remove the type identifier after a variable was already defined.

Comment: but I need use the if/else method to do that,I need different values. @Kevin Esche

Comment: @LeoLin: yes, but you don't need to re-declare the type each time. It only allows it to do it once, this doesn't mean you can't assign a (new) value

Comment: The error message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined variable rate multiple times , and hence you are getting compile time errors. Below fragment shall work fine.

```
public static double calculateTuition(int hour, char major, char state) {
           int rate=0;
           int labfee=0;
           double statusfee=0;
           if (hour >= 12) {
               rate = 800;
         } else {
               rate = hour * 70;
           }
           if (major == 'C'||major == 'c') {
               labfee = 25;
         } else if (major == 'O'||major == 'o') {
               labfee = 35;
         } else if (major == 'X'||major == 'x') {
               labfee = 0;
           }
           if (state == 'Y'||state == 'y') {
               statusfee = 5;
         } else if (state == 'N'||state == 'n') {
               statusfee = 5+ rate*.2;      
           }
           double tuition = rate+labfee+statusfee;
           return tuition;
           }
```

Comment: How about the **error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to double** for `double tuition = rate+""+labfee+""+statusfee;`

Comment: @LeoLin you return a double as defined in `static double calculateTuition` and not a `String`. If you want to return a `String` change it to `String` instead of `double.` (There is no need for the variable `tuition`, you can simply return the calculation)

Comment: @LeoLin i guess double tuition = rate+labfee+statusfee is perfectly fine.

Comment: `double tuition = rate+labfee+statusfee;` has **error: variable labfee might not have been initialized** and **error: variable statusfee might not have been initialized** @ Dark Knight

Comment: @LeoLin thanks for pointing that out, i have already intialized variables in above code. this should work fine.

Comment: New error for same sentence is **error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to double** @DarkKnight

Comment: @LeoLin did you try code shared in my answer?

Comment: Yes I did, I think `double statusfee=0` should be `double statusfee=0.0`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107622/discussion-between-dark-knight-and-leo-lin).

Answer (score 2):

Variable should be declared only once :

```
       int rate =0;
       int labfee =0;
       double statusfee =0;
       if (hour >= 12) {
          rate = 800;
     } else {
          rate = hour * 70;
       }
       if (major == 'C'||major == 'c') {
          labfee = 25;
     } else if (major == 'O'||major == 'o') {
          labfee = 35;
     } else if (major == 'X'||major == 'x') {
          labfee = 0;
       }
       if (state == 'Y'||state == 'y') {
          statusfee = 5;
     } else if (state == 'N'||state == 'n') {
          statusfee = 5+ rate*.2;      
       }
       double tuition = rate+labfee+statusfee;
       return tuition;
       }
```

Comment: you may want to use default values, if none of the if or elses runs, you 'll have double tuition = <don''t know> + <don't know> + <don't know>

Comment: also since they are local variables, you need to initialize them or you run into a compile time error.

Comment: @KevinEsche  Thanks Buddy. I missed it . Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have declared your variable once you dont have to declare it everytime you are using it. In your case you are defining it multiple times in your code and hence the error. Try this:

```
public static double calculateTuition(int hour, char major, char state) {
   int rate = 0;
   int labfee = 0;
   double statusfee = 0.0;
   double tuition = 0.0;
   if (hour >= 12) {
         rate = 800;
   } else {
      rate = hour * 70;
   }
   if (major == 'C'||major == 'c') {
      labfee = 25;
   } else if (major == 'O'||major == 'o') {
      labfee = 35;
   } else if (major == 'X'||major == 'x') {
      labfee = 0;
   }
   if (state == 'Y'||state == 'y') {
      statusfee = 5;
   } else if (state == 'N'||state == 'n') {
      statusfee = 5+ rate*.2;      
   }
   tuition = rate+labfee+statusfee;
   return tuition;
}
```

Comment: How about the **error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to double** for `double tuition = rate+""+labfee+""+statusfee;`

Comment: @LeoLin:- Did you try the same code which I have answered above?

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you.

Comment: @LeoLin:- You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

No need to declare the variable "rate" everytime. you already define it as local variable in your function so you can access it anywhere in your function.

Comment: Thank you, but how about the **error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to double** for `double tuition = rate+""+labfee+""+statusfee;`

Comment: what you exaclty want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the variable at the beginning of the method and again you are declaring and assigning the value multiple times in if and else statement.
Also initialize the local variables with some value.

```
public static double calculateTuition(int hour, char major, char state) {
           int rate =0;
           int labfee =0;
           double statusfee =0.0;
           if (hour >= 12) {
              rate = 800;
         } else {
              rate = hour * 70;
           }
           if (major == 'C'||major == 'c') {
              labfee = 25;
         } else if (major == 'O'||major == 'o') {
              labfee = 35;
         } else if (major == 'X'||major == 'x') {
              labfee = 0;
           }
           if (state == 'Y'||state == 'y') {
              statusfee = 5;
         } else if (state == 'N'||state == 'n') {
              statusfee = 5+ rate*.2;      
           }
           double tuition = rate+labfee+statusfee;
           return tuition;
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep variables as globally declared and do not declare it again in the same scope, you can edit your code as

```
public static double calculateTuition(int hour, char major, char state) {
int rate=0;
int labfee=0;
double statusfee=0.0,tuition=0.0;
if (hour >= 12) {
    rate = 800;
} else {
    rate = hour * 70;
}
if (major == 'C'||major == 'c') {
    labfee = 25;
} else if (major == 'O'||major == 'o') {
    labfee = 35;
} else if (major == 'X'||major == 'x') {
    labfee = 0;
}
if (state == 'Y'||state == 'y') {
    statusfee = 5;
} else if (state == 'N'||state == 'n') {
    statusfee = 5+ rate*.2;      
}
tuition = rate+labfee+statusfee;
return tuition;
}
```